# Server authorization with MD5 and SQL

Tags: python, sql, database, authorization, md5

I currently have a SQL database of passwords stored in MD5. The server needs to generate a unique key, then sends to the client. In the client, it will use the key as a salt then hash together with the password and send back to the server.

The only problem is that the the SQL DB has the passwords in MD5 already. Therefore for this to work, I would have to MD5 the password client side, then MD5 it again with the salt. Am I doing this wrong, because it doesn't seem like a proper solution. Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use SSL to encrypt the connection, then send the password over plain text from the client. The server will then md5 and compare with the md5 hash in the database to see if they are the same. If so `auth = success`.

MD5'ing the password on the client buys you nothing because a hacker with the md5 password can get in just as easy as if it was in plain text.

Comment: The question isn't about *MD5'ing the password on the client to increases security*. That's clearly pointless. It seems the poster wants to use a [Cryptographic nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) to implement secure authentication. The problem is that would normally requires both the user and the server to know the password. So the question really is *since the server already only store password hashes would hashing the password on the client make it possible to use a nonce?*   But then I have to agree using SSL in much simpler and secure.

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear to me what are you asking, but python [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib) (read the FAQ) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) should get you to where ever you are going.

For real world example in python check django [authentication](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) (the source).